# How to format or access properties of reverse geocoding results with Nominatim in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, nominatim, format, parse

I'm working on a small app where I want to collect the nearest street address from geotagged images. I have currently succeeded in pulling a PostGIS table into a geodataframe and running my points against Nominatim producing a new column with the address string. The string is returned with the street number first and with a lot of extraneous information. I'd like to format this string differently, or parse and format the results differently. I'm a bit unclear on if formatting the response can be done via the request, via the response object, or from the string (or all of the above)?

Here's my code without the import statements

```
df = gpd.read_postgis(sql, conn, geom_col="geom")
df['lon'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.x)
df['lat'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.y)
df['geocode'] = df['lat'].map(str) + ', ' + df['lon'].map(str)
locator = Nominatim(user_agent="pengMappingAgent", timeout=10)
rgeocode = RateLimiter(locator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=0.001)
tqdm.pandas()
df['address'] = df['geocode'].progress_apply(rgeocode)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('/Users/Nizz0k/Sites/python-spatial/address-pengs.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

What I'm trying to do is get one column with just the street name and number formatted to 'Street Name and Number' and another column with the neighborhood name. Essentially, I'm just not sure where the returned object's properties are and what's the best way to access them.

**Edit** my Python knowledge is limited, but it appears that this code doesn't return an object with the address properties. Running `list(globals().values())` in the terminal doesn't return anything that looks like it has the address info...